# Algorithm for inserting points in a piecewise-cubic Bézier path

Tags: algorithm, vector-graphics, bezier

I'm looking for an algorithm to insert a new control point on a Bézier curve, without deforming.

Does anybody know a library or reference for Bézier algorithms (insertion, optimize, de Casteljau ...)?

Comment: comp.graphics.algorithms FAQ, questions 4.02 and 4.03. In what language are you looking for a library?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is called the "knot insertion problem". For Bézier curves, the de Casteljau algorithm will give you the right answer. Here is the simple algorithm for a degree 3 Bézier.

Say you want to insert a knot at a fraction `t` of the parameter space inside the Bézier curve defined by `P0, P1, P2, P3`. Here's what you do:

```
P0_1 = (1-t)*P0 + t*P1
P1_2 = (1-t)*P1 + t*P2
P2_3 = (1-t)*P2 + t*P3

P01_12 = (1-t)*P0_1 + t*P1_2
P12_23 = (1-t)*P1_2 + t*P2_3

P0112_1223 = (1-t)*P01_12 + t*P12_23
```

Then your first Bézier will be defined by: `P_0, P0_1, P01_12, P0112_1223`; your second Bézier is defined by: `P0112_1223, P12_23, P2_3, P3`.

The geometrical interpretation is simple: you split each segment of the Bézier polygon at fraction `t`, then connect these split points in a new polygon and iterate. When you're left with 1 point, this point lies on the curve and the previous/next split points form the previous/next Bézier polygon. The same algorithm also works for higher degree Bézier curves.

Now it can get trickier if you want to insert the control point not at a specific value of `t` but at a specific location in space. Personally, what I would do here is simply a binary search for a value of `t` that falls close to the desired split point... But if performance is critical, you can probably find a faster analytic solution.

Comment: For a more efficient way to find the value t closest to a specific location in space, take a look at the paper referenced in my reply to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742610/closest-point-on-a-cubic-bezier-curve

Answer (score 2):

You could also take the mathematical approach.

A qubic Bézier curve with control points [image: p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4] can be written as:

[image: b(t)=(1-t)^3 p_1+3t(1-t)^2 p_2+3t^2 (1-t) p_3+t^3 p_4]

Its derivative w.r.t. [image: t] is

[image: \frac{\partial b}{\partial t} = 3(1-t)^2 (p_2-p_1 )+6t(1-t)(p_3-p_2 )+3t^2 (p_4-p_3 )]

To limit the curve from [image: t0] to [image: t1], you get new control points [image: q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4]:

[image: q_1=b(t_0),q_4=b(t_1)]

[image: q_2=q_1+\frac{1}{3}(t_1-t_0)\frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{t}}_{(t=t_0)}]

[image: q_3=q_4-\frac{1}{3}(t_1-t_0)\frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{t}}_{(t=t_1)}]

### Proof

Substituting

[image: s=\frac{t-t_0}{t_1-t_0}]

[image: t=t_0+s(t_1-t_0 )]

We get

[image: \frac{\partial b}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial b}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial s} = (t_1-t_0) \frac{\partial b}{\partial t}]

The first and last points of the sub-curve are the first and last new control points

[image: q_1=b(t_0),q_4=b(t_1)]

And the tangent at those points is

[image: \frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{s}}_{(s=0)}=(t_1-t_0)\frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{t}}_{(t=t_0)}=3(q_2-q_1)]

[image: \frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{s}}_{(s=1)}=(t_1-t_0)\frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{t}}_{(t=t_1)}=3(q_4-q_3)]

So

[image: q_2=q_1+\frac{1}{3}(t_1-t_0)\frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{t}}_{(t=t_0)}]

[image: q_3=q_4-\frac{1}{3}(t_1-t_0)\frac{\partial{b}}{\partial{t}}_{(t=t_1)}]

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for completeness.

An open-source implementation of many Bézier path operations can be found inside [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads) source code, in [`gimpbezierstroke.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/master/app/vectors/gimpbezierstroke.c). For reference on inserting a new anchor, search for `gimp_bezier_stroke_anchor_insert`.