# find the equation of a line from bezier curve control points

Tags: svg, bezier

I would like to find the equation of a curve in the form y = ax2 + bx + c

from the following svg path:

```
<path id="curve1"  d="M100,200 C100,100 400,100 400,200" />
```

this gives me 4 points that can be seen on the attached image.

- 100,200 (start point in purple)
- 100,100 (control point 1 in red)
- 400,100 (control point 2 in green)
- 400,200 (end point in blue)

wikipedia has a great article explaining bezier curves however I am not sure how to apply the maths shown there to get equation of the curve. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

[plotted curve, click to see image](https://40.media.tumblr.com/26847eb1d49586d208063a98543ffc53/tumblr_nkg7s5N31S1up03cjo1_500.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

The SVG you're showing uses a cubic path, which uses a third order parametric curve, meaning it has the form:

```
fx(t) = x1 * (1-t)³ + x2 * 3 * (1-t)²t + x3 * 3 * (1-t)t² + x4 * t³
fy(t) = y1 * (1-t)³ + y2 * 3 * (1-t)²t + y3 * 3 * (1-t)t² + y4 * t³
```

(which is plotted for `t` going from 0, inclusive, to 1, inclusive).

So there are two reasons why you can't express that curve as a form `y=ax²+b`:

1. you'd need, at the very least, a form `ax³+bx²+c` instead, and
2. this is a parametric curve, not a simple function graph; for Bezier curves it is not the case that `y` is expressed in terms of `x` at all, but instead *both* the `x` and `y` values are controlled by a "master parameter" `t`.

We know that second degree functions like `y=ax²+b` can only model parabola, and looking at the image we can see that the plotted curve looks nothing like one of those (not even a squashed parabola) so we can't even "kind of sort of" approximate the curve with a second degree function in this case.

(sometimes you can get away with that, but definitely not in this case)

Comment: Thank you Mike, I was reading your primer (http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) trying to figure out what to do. Is it possible to calculate the intersection of a cubic path and a straight line give by y = mx + c ?

Comment: it is: rotated the curve so that its x axis is aligned with that line, and then perform root finding on the curve (see http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#intersections)

Comment: given that I know: 
fx(t) = x1 * (1-t)³ + x2 * 3 * (1-t)²t + x3 * 3 * (1-t)t² + x4 * t³  & 
fy(t) = y1 * (1-t)³ + y2 * 3 * (1-t)²t + y3 * 3 * (1-t)t² + y4 * t³ 
and I have the three values of t, taken from your article  
(0.315, 0.041 and 0.932) 
and I know that y = 0 as we have aligned the straight line to the axis. 
Can I reuse the angle, ca, sa, ox and 0y variable from the align function to   find the intersection xy coordinates ? 
I do not need to draw the curve and was hoping not have have to find all XY values of the curve if i didn't need to.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mentioned I have changed the values of p0 - p4  and the two points of the straight line to match the ones shown in your article.
i.e. straight line:- (100,20) , (195,255) cubic curve:- (150,125),(40,30),(270,115),(145,200

Comment: you can't, but you can run what is known as [Cardano's algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823024/cubic-bezier-reverse-getpoint-equation-float-for-vector-vector-for-float) for always finding the three roots for the aligned curve (although some could be complex, so we reject those)