# Closest point on a B-Spline Curve?

Tags: graphics, geometry, curve, spline

This thread asks how to get the closest point on a Bezier curve given an arbitrary point on the same plane: [Closest point on a cubic Bezier curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742610/closest-point-on-a-cubic-bezier-curve)

How can I accomplish the same thing but for a B-SPline curve?

Comment: Apply the point-to-Bezier-curve algorithm to the Bezier curve converted from each segment of the B-spline curve then find out the global minimum.